# Hex characters in varchar() is actually ascii. Need to decode it

Tags: sql, encoding, ascii, hex, decoding

This is such an edge-case of a question, I'd be surprised if there is an easy way to do this.

I have a MS SQL DB with a field of type varchar(255).  It contains a hex string which is actually a Guid when you decode it using an ascii decoder.  I know that sounds REALLY weird but here's an example:

The contents of the field: "38353334373838622D393030302D343732392D383436622D383161336634396339663931"

What it actually represents: "8534788b-9000-4729-846b-81a3f49c9f91"

I need a way to decode this, and just change the contents of the field to the actual guid it represents.  I need to do this in T-SQL, I cannot use .Net (which if I could, that is remarkably simple).

**UPDATE**: Some people have responded with ways that may work in one-off statements, I need a way to put this into an UPDATE statement.

For example:  UPDATE MyTable SET MyField = MyFunction(MyField)

Where MyFunction is the correct answer to this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this will give you what you want..8534788b-9000-4729-846b-81a3f49c9f91

```
select CONVERT(varchar(36),
0x38353334373838622D393030302D343732392D383436622D383161336634396339663931)
```

you need to convert the value to varbinary and then convert back to varchar

here is one way using dynamic SQL

```
    declare @v varchar(100)
 select @v = '0x' + '38353334373838622D393030302D343732392D383436622D383161336634396339663931'

exec ( 'SELECT CONVERT(varchar(36),' + @v + ')')
```

Comment: That gets me half of the way, but how to I get to the varbinary?  If I do 
select convert(varbinary(max),'FF')
it gives me 0x4646, where in my case the string should be 0xFF

Comment: Thanks! This will definitely work, I didn't consider using dynamic SQL. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert individual characters you can do it with the `CHAR` function as:

```
SELECT CHAR(0x38)
```

But you have to remember to prefix the number with 0x since it's hexadecimal.